# Proving a Limit in a deleted neighborhood

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f(x) \geq 0$ in some deleted neighborhood of the point $c$, and if $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow c} f(x)$ = $L$. I seek to prove that $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow c} \sqrt{f(x)} = \sqrt{L}$ under the assumption that $L>0$.

I know I can say that $$ \left|\sqrt{f(x)} - \sqrt{L}\right|=\frac{|f(x)-L|}{\sqrt{f(x)} + \sqrt{L}} \leq \frac{|f(x)-L|}{\sqrt{L}}$$

But how can I complete the proof from there?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are done. You can squeeze.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost done.

Suppose $D$ be the stated deleted neighborhood of $c.$

Since $\lim_{x \rightarrow c} f(x)$ = $L,$ so for $\epsilon>0~\exists~\delta_1>0$ such that  $|f(x)-L|<\sqrt L\epsilon$ whenever $|x-c|<\delta$ where $N(c,\delta)$ is small enough to fit in $D.$

So |$ \sqrt{f(x)} - \sqrt{L}|=$ $\dfrac{|f(x)-L|}{\sqrt{f(x)} + \sqrt{L}}$ $\leq$ $\dfrac{|f(x)-L|}{\sqrt{L}}<\dfrac{\sqrt L \epsilon}{\sqrt L}=\epsilon$ whenever $|x-c|<\delta.$